# ANTLR4 Order in Recursive Rule

Tags: antlr4

I want to describe DELPHI's BEGIN/END blocs.

I use the following source code as input :

```
begin
  ModalResult         := mrCancel;
  FGradient.Free;
  if FMemorizeDimensions then
  begin
    if ERROR_SUCCESS = RegCreateKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
                   PChar(gcsREG_KEYBASE),
                   hkResult) then
    try
      dwValueType := REG_DWORD;
      dwValue := Ord(WindowState);
      dwValueSize := SizeOf(dwValue);

    finally
      RegCloseKey(hkResult);
    end;
  end;
  inherited;
end;
```

Here is a part of my grammar :

```
bloc
:BEGIN
     statement
    |conditionalBloc
    |bloc
 END SEMI
;
```

I have no problem generating parser, lexer and so on ...

But when i try to use this other grammar (switching 'conditionalBloc' and 'bloc'):

```
bloc
:BEGIN

    statement
    |bloc
    |conditionalBloc
 END SEMI
;
```

I am getting this exception :

```
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
    java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
    sorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.antlr.v4.parse.GrammarTreeVisitor.visit(GrammarTreeVisitor.java:2
    07)
    at org.antlr.v4.parse.GrammarTreeVisitor.visitGrammar(GrammarTreeVisitor
    .java:201)
    at org.antlr.v4.semantics.SymbolCollector.process(SymbolCollector.java:7
    6)
    at org.antlr.v4.semantics.SemanticPipeline.process(SemanticPipeline.java
    :103)
    at org.antlr.v4.Tool.processNonCombinedGrammar(Tool.java:397)
    at org.antlr.v4.Tool.process(Tool.java:384)
    at org.antlr.v4.Tool.processGrammarsOnCommandLine(Tool.java:343)
    at org.antlr.v4.Tool.main(Tool.java:190)
    Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at org.antlr.v4.semantics.SymbolCollector.discoverOuterAlt(SymbolCollect
    or.java:111)
    at org.antlr.v4.parse.GrammarTreeVisitor.outerAlternative(GrammarTreeVis
    itor.java:2285)
    at org.antlr.v4.parse.GrammarTreeVisitor.ruleBlock(GrammarTreeVisitor.ja
    va:2198)
    at org.antlr.v4.parse.GrammarTreeVisitor.rule(GrammarTreeVisitor.java:16
    64)
    at org.antlr.v4.parse.GrammarTreeVisitor.rules(GrammarTreeVisitor.java:1
    242)
    at org.antlr.v4.parse.GrammarTreeVisitor.grammarSpec(GrammarTreeVisitor.
    java:481)
    ... 12 more
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.antlr.v4.tool.Rule.getAltLabels(Rule.java:212)
    at org.antlr.v4.tool.Rule.hasAltSpecificContexts(Rule.java:200)
    at org.antlr.v4.semantics.SymbolChecks.checkForLabelConflicts(SymbolChec
    ks.java:151)
    at org.antlr.v4.semantics.SymbolChecks.process(SymbolChecks.java:99)
    at org.antlr.v4.semantics.SemanticPipeline.process(SemanticPipeline.java
    :107)
    at org.antlr.v4.Tool.processNonCombinedGrammar(Tool.java:397)
    at org.antlr.v4.Tool.process(Tool.java:384)
    at org.antlr.v4.Tool.processGrammarsOnCommandLine(Tool.java:343)
    at org.antlr.v4.Tool.main(Tool.java:190)
```

Can someone help me understand this situation please ?

Comment: It would be helpful to see you definitions of statement, bloc and conditionalBloc. And perhaps the whole grammar, if not too large ;o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is a reformatted copy of your `bloc` rule using the ANTLR 4 order of operations:

```
bloc
  : BEGIN statement
  | bloc
  | conditionalBloc END SEMI
  ;
```

I believe this is what you meant instead:

```
bloc
  : BEGIN
    ( statement
    | bloc
    | conditionalBloc
    )
    END SEMI
  ;
```

The exception is a failure to handle the recursive `bloc` alternative which does not contain anything after the left-recursive reference. You can open an issue on the project issue tracker here:

https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues

Comment: This is not what i meant ! I had trouble understanding when i needed to use parentheses or not in a rule.
My small example let me think it was not needed but i was definitely wrong.
After reading some documentations it's clear to me now.
Thank You